# awk: transform certain lines based on pattern, print the rest as-is

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I have an `awk` command that looks like this:

`awk -F ',' '{print $3 "," $4 "," $2 ", " $1 "," $5 "," $6}`

It works great, except that it works with every line in a file, which I don't need. I want to limit it to work only with the lines that contain a certain pattern. So I pipe in another command:

`(awk -F ',' '{print $3 "," $4 "," $2 ", " $1 "," $5 "," $6} | awk '/mypattern/')`

This works, but now it prints *only* those lines containing the pattern and erases the lines that don't.

I'd like to limit the command to working only with the lines containing the pattern and to leave the lines that don't contain the pattern as-is. It seems that is possible using an if statement, but I am having trouble figuring out how to integrate `awk`'s conditional syntax using my current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

same solution, more idiomatic

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} /pat/{print $3,$4,$2,$1,$5,$6; next}1' file

1,2,3,4,5,6
3,4,2,1,pat,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

for the input file

```
$ cat file

1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,pat,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: This is very simple and works well for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F ',' '/mypattern/ {print $3 "," $4 "," $2 ", " $1 "," $5 "," $6} !/mypattern/'
```

*Aside*: is there a reason for the [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) in your example? i.e. `( awk -F ',' ... )` ?

Comment: I took the command out of its context. It is a part of a string of piped commands.

Comment: I see. Anyhow, don't store commands in a variable. Variables hold data. **Functions** hold code.

Answer (score 3):

Given `file.csv` contains:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3boo,4,5,6
```

Try this awk:

```
$ awk -F ',' '{
                        if (/boo/)
                                print $3 "," $4 "," $2 ", " $1 "," $5 "," $6
                        else
                                print $0
                }' "file.csv"
```

Successfully results:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
3boo,4,2, 1,5,6
```

### Explanation

- Written on multiple lines for clarity
- `/boo/` is a sample pattern to match
- Uses conditional construct `if (condition)` ... `else`
- Only single statement in each then-clause, so can simplify by omit `{` `}` for then clauses
- For the `else`, to leave the line as-is without changing it, we use `print $0` which prints the entire line

Comment: While I didn't choose your answer, it is helpful because it illustrates `awk`'s conditional syntax well. So thank you!